# Creating bidimensional array's size with the input values

Tags: c++, arrays, size

First of all, happy new year!

So, I'd like to ask if I could use some input values as the size of a bidimensional array, for example:

I'd like to know, if instead of doing this:

```
const int N = 10;
const int M = 10;
typedef int IntMatrix[N][M];
```

Let's say that would be the max size of the array I could create, but then the user inputs that the size must have a size of 5x5. I know I could then use 5x5 as a limit when doing stuff, but could I do like the same, but using the input values as the dimension of the Matrix?
Something like:

```
cin >> N >> M;
```

And then use that as the MAX size of each dimension. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, you can't do that according standards. Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how does that work? The std stuff, I've never used that

Comment: Here's a pretty good reference:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

No. The size of an array must be known at compile time and can not be determined at runtime as described in [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) for example. Therefore, the size of the array cannot depend on user input.

What you can do, is allocate an array dynamically and store it's address in a pointer. The size of a dynamic array can be [determined at runtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/). However, there is a problem. Only the outermost dimension of a dynamically allocated 2D array may be determined at runtime. You have 2 options: Either you allocate a flat array of size NxM where the rows are stored continuously one after the other and you calculate the index using maths. Or, you use an array of pointers and assign each pointer to a dynamically allocated array column. The first option is more efficient.

There is another problem. Dynamic memory management is hard, and it's never a good idea to do it manually even if you know what you're doing. Much less if you don't. There is a container class in the standard library which takes care of memory management of dynamic arrays. It's [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Always use it when you need a dynamic array. Your options stay similar. Either use a flat, NxM size vector, or a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The array should be dynamically allocatedn because array size should be known at compile-time. You can do this way:

```
int N,M; // Dimensions
int** intMatrix; // Array of array
std::cin << N << M; 

intMatrix = new int*[N]; // Allocate N the row

for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
intMatrix[i] = new int[M]; // For each row, allocate the col
}

// aaaand don't forget to free memory like this:
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
   delete [] intMatrix[i];
}

delete [] intMatrix;
```

Comment: Advising to use `new` directly is bad.

Comment: Being dogmatic is bad :)
Why ?

Comment: Smart pointers and container classes are there for good reasons. Don't try to be smarter than the developers of the C++ standards.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, there is no "bad" or "good" solutions. (But I agree, using dynamic alloc. can be a little tricky)

Comment: Both `delete` statements you presented first were wrong. One of the reasons you should not do that yourself. It's a very common error.